# Is a quotient space isomorphic to its orthogonal

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

The quotient space of a normed space $(X, \|\cdot\|_X)$ by a closed subspace $M\subset X$ is the normed space $(X/M, \|\cdot\|_{X/M})$ defined as follows
\begin{align*}
X/M= \{\dot{x}=x+M: x\in X\}\quad \text{and}\quad \|\dot{x}\|_{X/M}=\inf\big\{ \|x-y\|_{X}: y\in M\big\}=dist(x,M). 
\end{align*}
Recall that each $\dot{x}= x+M=\{x+y: y\in M\}$ represents a equivalence class associated with the equivalence relation $\sim$ for which  $x\sim y$  if and only if $x-y\in M$.

The orthogonal of $M$ is defined as follows
$$M^\perp= \{\ell\in X^*: \ell(x)=0 \quad \text{for all}  \quad x\in M\}=  \{\ell\in X^*: M\subset \ker\ell\}. $$

Where $X^*$ is the dual of $X$.

Question Prove or disprove that the spaces  $M^\perp$ and $X/M$ are isomorphic. We assume that $M$ is proper subspace of $X$.

For the case $\dim X<\infty$ it is obvious that $M^\perp$ and $X/M$ are isomorphic since  $$\dim M^\perp= \dim X/M= \dim X-\dim M$$

Comment: Not a response to your query, but what does it mean when you write $X^*$ is the dual of $X$? I can't find an explanation of that online.

Comment: @integer The dual space is the collection of all bounded linear functionals on $X$.

Comment: Much appreciated, @Mark. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that $(X/M)^* \cong M^\perp$, so a space $X$ and a subspace $M$ such that $(X/M)^* \not\cong X/M$ will do the job.

Take $M=0$. Then you are asked to find a space $X$ with $X^* \not\cong X$, and there are plenty of such spaces.